# Proof that a set of matrices form a group. Is it a Lie group? Calculate the generators

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, abelian-groups

I have to proof that the set of matrices that verify this equation form a group.In that case, iis it a lie Group? Which is the dimension? Note that the we are working in the complex space C in 4 dimensions.

So far i have found that this group of matrices is called Complex Lorentz Group.(Is it a subgroup of the pseudo-unitary group(3,1). In this case we are working with a signature diag(-1,1,1,1)

How can if find the generators of the group?Dimensions of the generators?

And the last question,is there any subgroups such a cartan subalgebra or casimir opreartor

Image of the problem:

[image: Image of the problem]

Comment: I am not sure what you mean when you say that you want to find the "generators of the group", but my best guess is that you are looking for the [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) associated with your Lie group; is that correct?  By the "dimensions of the generators", I think that you are asking for the dimension of the Lie algebra. Is that correct? For your last question: are you simply asking whether the group has any subgroups?

Comment: Title: Yes, matrix groups are Lie groups.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** A matrix $X$ will be an element of the Lie Algebra associated with the Lie Group $G$ if for all $t \in \Bbb R$, we have $\exp(tX) \in G$ (or $\exp(itX) \in G$ if you are using the physics convention).

Note that $U\exp(tX)U^\dagger = \exp(t \,UXU^\dagger)$.